# Which interface is used to detect key events from the Dialog class (Android SDK)?

Tags: android, sdk, dialog, onkeyup, onkeydown

I've created a simple custom dialog that asks users to "Press a key".  The purpose of this is so that I can map whatever key they press to a function in the app.  Unfortunately, I can not figure out what is the correct interface to use to detect the key events.  My class looks like this:

```
public class ScancodeDialog extends Dialog implements OnKeyListener
{

    public ScancodeDialog( Context context )
    {
        super(context);
        setContentView( R.layout.scancode_dialog );
        setTitle( "Key Listener" );
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.scancode_text );
        text.setText( "Please press a button.." );
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.scancode_image );
        image.setImageResource( R.drawable.icon );
        getWindow().setFlags( WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM,
                              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey( DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
    {
        if( keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU )
            dismiss();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tried it with and without the getWindow().setFlags() line (that was a suggestion from another question, which didn't help me in my case).  Obviously I will add more functionality to the class later, but for now the dialog box should close whenever the user presses a key.  However, onKey is never called.

I originally tried using the key listener interface from View:

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
```

But since a Dialog is not a view, this didn't work.  I also tried the one from DialogInterface:

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;
```

This seemed like a better choice, since the API indicates that Dialog implements DialogInterface, but I am still not receiving the key events.  Any suggestions I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never declared the dialog to listen to the keys.

Example:

```
this.setOnKeyListener(...)
```

the this keyword is referring to the class that it is in.. which is a Dialog.

Comment: The onkey listener is 'this'.. do I just go "this.setOnKeyListener(this)"?  That seems redundant, but I'll try..

Comment: That worked, you're a genius!  I never would have thought to try that.  A+++

Comment: Or you could try an anonymous listener instead of implementing the entire thing.