# Android Dialog OnKeyUp (KeyEvent)?

Tags: android, xamarin, keyevent

I have a dialog and on in this dialog I have a button.  When pressed search is suppose to appear.  And this works completely fine.

BUT I want to able to set up `OnKeyUp` event so if the user clicks on the actual search button on the phone (not on the screen), search view appears.

I was able to do this in an activity this way:

```
public override bool OnKeyUp(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Search) {
        // do something here
    }
    return base.OnKeyUp (keyCode, e);
}
```

But that's an `override` method.  How do I call that for a `Dialog`?
This is how I've created the `Dialog`:

```
multiSelectDialog = new Dialog (context);
multiSelectDialog.RequestWindowFeature (1);
multiSelectDialog.SetContentView (dialogView);
multiSelectDialog.Show ();
```

Dialog has the OnKeyUp property.

```
multiSelectDialog.OnKeyUp(KeyCode.Search, KeyEvent e);
```

But I am not sure how to create a `KeyEvent`.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post your dialog code.

Comment: You will probably need to create your own custom dialog class.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529653/which-interface-is-used-to-detect-key-events-from-the-dialog-class-android-sdk

Comment: @DanielNugent I am not sure what dialog code you are asking for.  Do you mean the actual `dialogView` view code?

Answer (score 1):

`onKeyUp()` is a callback on `Dialog`, it will be called on a key-up event, you don't call it yourself.

Instead you have to extend `Dialog` and override `onKeyUp()`, for example:

```
multiSelectDialog = new Dialog(context) {
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // do something here
        return true; // or false, depending on what you want to do
    }
};
multiSelectDialog.requestWindowFeature(1);
multiSelectDialog.setContentView(dialogView);
multiSelectDialog.show();
```